# CSV to Mysql with Python 2.7 on windows7

Tags: python, csv, mysql-python

I get this error, when im trying to run my code :

```js
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/mysql2.py", line 7, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 219, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 38, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
OperationalError: (1300, 'Invalid utf8 character string: \'"\'')"
```

This is the code:

```js
import MySQLdb

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="1234", db="database")

cursor = connection.cursor()
query2 = '''LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/Python27/output.csv" INTO TABLE    valami COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;'''
cursor.execute(query2)

connection.close()
```

My csv file has 4 columns (with a header). Whats wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

This bit

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

gets interpreted by Python and means a newline. But you really want to pass `\n` to your query.

Use a raw string:

```
query2 = r'''LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/Python27/output.csv" INTO TABLE (etc)'''
```